# lightbox effect on wordpress post attached images

Tags: function, wordpress, lightbox

I have this code to display the attached images on a post:

```
<?php   

 $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'attachment',
   'numberposts' => -1,
   'post_status' => null,
   'post_parent' => $post->ID,
   'exclude'     => get_post_thumbnail_id()
  );

  $attachments = get_posts( $args );
     if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
           echo '<a href="';
           echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID );
           echo '" rel="lightbox">';
           echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'large' );
           echo '</a>';
          }
     }

  ?>
```

But i cannot work out why the Lightbox is not working! I have tried colorbox, shadowbox, ligthbox plugins etc... it just does not load. When you click on the image, it just opens in page.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: There are tons of lightbox plugins, which one do you want to use ?

Comment: Well lets say lightbox 2. I have tried with all of them however, and it just does not load in the lightbox. I don't know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: http://franklinbishop.net/6-lightbox-plugins-for-wordpress/

Comment: this is not helpful. As i said, i have tried all of them.

Comment: You don't have to try all of them, you have to adapt your code depending on the plugin you are using... Don't think plugins can automagically work with your code... So what is exactly your lightbox plugin ?

Comment: I have tried all of them, adapting my code to them... i may not understand much, but i'm not an idiot. I have adapted my code to suite the plugins... but it seems there may be a problem with my general code.

Answer (score 0):

See if your theme call

```
wp_head();
```

in your header file and

```
wp_footer();
```

in your footer file the plugins don't work if youar missing this.

Comment: The theme does call this. I am using the Grid-a-Licous theme.